# DNS setting update help and also Output results

Tags: powershell

Two part question, help needed.

#### End goal is to find all Member Servers in AD who are online and have a specific DNS entry in the settings.

I would like to dump those list of servers into a CSV just like how it displays on the screen. So I can review it before doing the next part of the question. Whenever I add Out-File or Export-CSV I get header information for every server and a bunch of spacing.  The formatting doesn't reflect what I see on the screen.

I would also like to add the extra bit of code that will update those DNS settings to a different one if it matches the criteria I specified.  I'm just having a little trouble on both.  All of member servers are either 2008r2 or 2003.  So I can't use new Powershell DNS code.

```
##Query for computer objects with a Server OS
$servers = get-adcomputer -LDAPFilter "(&(objectcategory=computer)(operatingsystem=*server*))"|select-object name

$arr=@()
##For every server found above do the following.
foreach($server in $servers)
{
    ##Test to see if Server is online through Ping.
    $test = test-connection -cn $server.name -count 1 -quiet

    ##If server is online do the following.
    if($test -match 'True')
    {
        ##From those servers that are found online, check to see if they are classified as a "Member Server".  We don't want DC's.
        $memberservers = gwmi win32_computersystem -cn $server.name -filter "domainrole='3'"|Select-Object name

        ##For some reason i get an empty server name from the list above.  So i get rid of those.
        if($memberservers.name -ne $null)
        {
            ##Find out if any of those servers have the following IP as there DNS settings.
            $DNSResults=gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration -cn $memberservers.name|`
            where-object{$_.dnsserversearchorder -match "10.100.1.50" -and $_.ipenabled -match "true"}|`
            select-object dnshostname,@{Name='dnsserversearchorder';Expression={[string]::join(";",($_.dnsserversearchorder))}}
            
            $arr+=$DNSResults
            $DNSResults.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(10.100.1.51,10.100.1.52)
        }
    }
}
$arr|Export-csv C:\results.csv
```

Comment: So what is the question

Comment: Hi.  sorry about that.  I guess after re reading my post you're right.  I wasn't clear.  I wanted to collaborate with the two issues I was having.  First question, the last If statement where i'm querying for DNS entries, I wanted to get the output displayed on the screen into a CSV.  When I attempt to put Out-file the data is ugly when I use -append. Because it's adding headers for every single member server.  So i'm not sure if i'm using out-file in the wrong area.

Comment: Second question the part of actually changing the DNS entries for those servers that need it updated.  Would I use SetDNSServerSearchOrder within another IF statement?

Comment: regarding your second question maybe you want to have a look at this thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/033b4053-d73c-4fb6-a6c0-2b6dfc8ac558/powershell-script-leveraging-wmi-setdnsserversearchorderdns-method-dns-addresses-cached?forum=ITCG for a solution to your question but also a followup problem you might have to deal with

Comment: I will give it a shot for the export.  In reference to the second link.  Funny you mentioned that.  We recently ran into that issue when we manually changed DNS settings on two of our 2008 member servers.  They lost there record after a reboot.  After opening a call to Microsoft.  They provided us a hotfix to apply to all of our DNS servers.  http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2520155.  I will look at the code for the tidbits I need.  Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you.  Your recommendation worked.  for the output. Exactly what I wanted.  How do I give you credit?  I don't see a spot for me to mark the answer?

Comment: I also updated the code above to reflect the changes. Thx.  :)

Comment: i have added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question:

Before your foreach loop create an empty array

```
$arr=@()
```

then in the loop add the output to the array

```
$obj = gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration -cn $memberservers.name ...  
$arr+= $obj
```

and after the loop export it

```
$arr | export-csv
```